# Multiple aggregated Counting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DF:

```
data = [["John","144","Smith","200"], ["Mia","220","John","144"],["Caleb","155","Smith","200"],["Smith","200","Jason","500"]]
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ["Name","ID","Manager_name","Manager_ID"])
data_frame
```

OP:

```
    Name    ID    Manager_name  Manager_ID
  0 John    144    Smith             200
  1 Mia     220    John              144
  2 Caleb   155    Smith             200
  3 Smith   200    Jason             500
```

I am trying to count the number of people reporting under each person in the column Name.

Logic is:

Count the number of people reporting individually and people reporting under in the chain. For example with Smith; John and Caleb reports to Smith so 2 + 1 with Mia reporting to John (who already reports to Smith) so total 3.

Similarly for Jason -> 1 because Smith reports to him and 3 people already report to Smith so total 4.

I understand how to do it pythonically with some recursion, is there a way to efficiently do it in Pandas. Any suggestions?

Expected OP:

```
Name        Number of people reporting
John               1
Mia                0
Caleb              0
Smith              3
Jason              4
```

Comment: this sounds like a union-find problem. Would be interesting to see a pandas solution.

Comment: This is a [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) problem and look at using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.3/) library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is also, a graph problem and you can use [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.3/):

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
data = [["John","144","Smith","200"], ["Mia","220","John","144"],["Caleb","155","Smith","200"],["Smith","200","Jason","500"]]
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ["Name","ID","Manager_name","Manager_ID"])

#create a directed graph object using nx.DiGraph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data_frame, 
                            source='Name', 
                            target='Manager_name', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())

#use nx.ancestors to get set of "ancenstor" nodes for each node in the directed graph
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i:len(nx.ancestors(G,i)) for i in G.nodes()}, 
                       orient='index', 
                       columns=['Num of People reporting'])
```

Output:

```
       Num of People reporting
John                         1
Smith                        3
Mia                          0
Caleb                        0
Jason                        4
```

Draw newtorkx:

[image]

Comment: What version of Networkx are you using?. I am getting an error "module networkx has no attribute 'from_pandas_edgelist'

Comment: Sure. Thanks for this solution. This library is a whole new learning for me today!!!

Comment: @Scott Boston thanks for pointing this library out, i also did not know it existed! This is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 7):

> Scott Boston's Networkx solution is the preferred solution...

There are two solutions to this problem. The first one is a vectorized pandas type solution and should be fast over larger datasets,  the second is pythonic and does not work well on the size of dataset the OP was looking for, the original df size is (223635,4).

> 1. PANDAS SOLUTION

This problem seeks to find out how many people each person in an organization manages, including subordinate's subordinates. This solution will create a dataframe by adding successive columns that are the managers of the previous columns, and then counting the occurance of each employee in that dataframe to determine the total number under them.

First we set up the input.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ["John", "144", "Smith", "200"],
    ["Mia", "220", "John", "144"],
    ["Caleb", "155", "Smith", "200"],
    ["Smith", "200", "Jason", "500"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "SID", "Manager_name", "Manager_SID"])

df = df[["SID", "Manager_SID"]]

# shortening the columns for convenience
df.columns = ["1", "2"]

print(df)

     1    2
0  144  200
1  220  144
2  155  200
3  200  500
```

First the employees without subordinates must be counted and put into a seperate dictionary.

```
df_not_mngr = df.loc[~df['1'].isin(df['2']), '1']
non_mngr_dict = {str(key):0 for key in df_not_mngr.values}
non_mngr_dict

{'220': 0, '155': 0}
```

Next we will modify the dataframe by adding columns of managers of the previous column. The loop is stopped when there are no employees in the right most column

```
for i in range(2, 10):
    df = df.merge(
        df[["1", "2"]], how="left", left_on=str(i), right_on="1", suffixes=("_l", "_r")
    ).drop("1_r", axis=1)
    df.columns = [str(x) for x in range(1, i + 2)]
    if df.iloc[:, -1].isnull().all():
        break
    else:
        continue
print(df)

    1    2    3    4    5
0  144  200  500  NaN  NaN
1  220  144  200  500  NaN
2  155  200  500  NaN  NaN
3  200  500  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

All columns except the first columns are collapsed and each employee counted and added to a dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter

result = dict(Counter(df.iloc[:, 1:].values.flatten()))
```

The non manager dictionary is added to the result.

```
result.update(non_mngr_dict)
result

{'200': 3, '500': 4, nan: 8, '144': 1, '220': 0, '155': 0}
```

> 2. RECURSIVE PYTHONIC SOLUTION

I think this is probably way more pythonic than you were looking for. First I created a list 'all_sids' to make sure we capture all employees as not all are in each list.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ["John", "144", "Smith", "200"],
    ["Mia", "220", "John", "144"],
    ["Caleb", "155", "Smith", "200"],
    ["Smith", "200", "Jason", "500"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "SID", "Manager_name", "Manager_SID"])

all_sids = pd.unique(df[['SID', 'Manager_SID']].values.ravel('K'))
```

Then create a pivot table.

```
dfp = df.pivot_table(values='Name', index='SID', columns='Manager_SID', aggfunc='count')
```

dfp

```
Manager_SID  144  200  500
SID                       
144          NaN  1.0  NaN
155          NaN  1.0  NaN
200          NaN  NaN  1.0
220          1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Then a function that will go through the pivot table to total up all the reports.

```
def count_mngrs(SID, count=0):
    if str(SID) not in dfp.columns:
        return count
    else:
        count += dfp[str(SID)].sum()
        sid_list = dfp[dfp[str(SID)].notnull()].index
        for sid in sid_list:
            count = count_mngrs(sid, count)
        return count
```

Call the function for each employee and print the results.

```
print('SID', '     Number of People Reporting')
for sid in all_sids: 
    print(sid, "     " , int(count_mngrs(sid)))
```

Results are below, sorry I was a bit lazy in putting the names with the sids.

```
SID      Number of People Reporting
144       1
220       0
155       0
200       3
500       4
```

Look forward to seeing a more pandas type solution!

Comment: This is great!!! Yep this is pretty much what I did too. Hope we can see a more pandas solution.

Comment: I figured as much but it was a fun puzzle, thanks for sharing.

Comment: When I try to run the pivot table, I am getting an error

Comment: Hmm, what error? When I cut and paste it back into Jupyter it is running for me.

Comment: The original  df size is (223635,4).

Comment: IndexError:  index 165973228 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 165968257.

Comment: Dang that's big

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192615/discussion-between-run-out-and-vijay-dahiya).

Comment: This is great!!

Comment: Ha, wish I had seen Scott's solution yesterday! Glad it all worked out, the Networkx solution is cool. Cheers,